# What will be the ill effects of turning off and on server daily

Tags: vmware-esxi, electrical-power, rsa, ibm-xseries

I have [IBM server x 3850 M2](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4362.pdf) with remote system adapter.

It has 128GB RAM and 4 SAS drives

Its basically for my home labs , developmenet and testing

I think that if i make it on 24 x 7 then i will be wasting power as i only use it when i come home or weekends

Power it cosumes is around 380W which almost ends up $50 bill per month

As i have RSA i can turn on anytime when required.

but i don't know whether it is bad for the server to shutdown and restart everyday and turn it on 24 X 7

I have read that Harddrives can fail if i do that but i think thats not the issue. i think the amount of bill i save each month is good enough to buy the drives even if they fail every 4-5 months

The main thing i need to know is about other server components like processor , RAM, Motherboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server should be fine - put a decent power filter on it.

If you think about it, the average PC is designed to be switched on and off on a regular basis, and last years.  Things like memory, processors and motherboards won't have a problem with it - and for that matter, while you might shorten the lives of hard drives, its not going to be a big issue - certainly not one that comes anywhere close to the power savings.

Comment: Wrong. It will be fine but it is using a lot of starts on the drives. Not sure about your world, but in mine most SAS drives have a limited number of restarts. THAT SAID: Seagate on my 450db drives guarantees 2 startups per day for 5 years, so a start every other day would be fine in the warranty area. SAS drives are not average PCs.

Comment: @TomTom Where exactly do we disagree ?  Also, The OP was not worried about the H/D - he wanted to know about RAM, Motherboard.

Comment: Only on details - you also got no downvote ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question. I use my servers for projects and have no need to run them 24/7, however, the problem that I've run into is the array batteries not charging and giving errors when I do finally boot up the servers again.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I would think off is thermal stress, but it's not a major problem.